# golang,How to transfer an http(s) proxy to a socks5 proxy

Tags: go, socks5

Does proxy.SOCKS5 support keepalive, why do my long links break every 25-26 seconds?
I want to convert the http(s) proxy request into a socks5 proxy, and then go back, do you have a way?
How does Golang http(s) translate to socks5？

Comment: it is likely due to a timeout setting on either the client or server side!